# Make UIView under a UITableView visible when you scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, background

I have a UITableView that's placed on top of a UIView.

So basically, it looks like this:
I have a tableviewHolder which has two subviews
1.) UIView with other subviews 
2.) UITableView

Whenever the user scrolls the UITableView, i want the UIView beneath it to be visible. 
I tried setting the UITableView's background to clear and it works. However, if the tableview's background is clear, then other portion of the UIView beneath it would be visible when the rows of the cell are not enough to cover the whole table.
How can I change the background color of the table view and still make the UIView beneath it visible whenever the user scrolls?

Comment: You mean you only want to see the background where cells are, but not where there aren't any - i.e. below the lowest cell?

Comment: If I understand your question, you'd have to dynamically alter the size of the tableViews cells depening on how many cells you have to achieve the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

(ref https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillBeginDragging: )

This method will be called when the UITableView begins scrolling. So, in this method, set the UIView to visible

```
view.setAlpha=1.0;
```

and in

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

set the uIView to invisible again by using

```
view.setAlpha=0.0;
```

Am asking you to use UIScrollViewDelegate methods in a UITableViewDelegate class. This will work because UITableViewDelegate inherits from UIScrollViewDelegate. So all methods in UIScrollViewDelegate will also work for UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: so yeah. what I did is, every time the scroll view scrolls, i resize (based on the contentOffset) the view beneath the tableview so it would seem like it's visible. When the scrollview is not scrolling, i set the alpha to 0. thanks for this!